# Segmentation fault running layers.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a simple test script to illustrate the problem I am having. I am trying to implement a CNN using tensorflow, but I started running into segmentation fault when changing the size of the input. In the test script, I can successfully run it if n_H=3000. But I got a segmentation fault when I set n_H=4000. In addition, if I run it without layars.conv2d by setting with_conv=False, the script runs successfully. Does anyone has any idea what my problem is?

I am running this on a host with 12 CPUs. I don't really understand the messages from tensorflow about "Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2". I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem.

Here is the output when I get a segmentation fault:

```
$ python test.py
(100, 4000, 100, 1) (100, 8)
2018-10-10 11:57:23.825704: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2
2018-10-10 11:57:23.827653: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:69] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x00007fea9af1a740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350 in _call_tf_sessionrun
  File "/home/seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1263 in _run_fn
  File "/home/seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278 in _do_call
  File "/home/seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1272 in _do_run
  File "/home/seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100 in _run
  File "/home/seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877 in run
  File "test.py", line 43 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is test script:

```
import faulthandler; faulthandler.enable()
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

seed = 42
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

num_examples = 100
n_H = 4000
with_conv = True

# generate training data
X_gen = np.random.randn(num_examples*n_H*100).reshape(num_examples, n_H, 100, 1)
Y_gen = np.random.randn(num_examples*8).reshape(num_examples, 8)    
X_train = X_gen[0:num_examples, 0:n_H, ...]
Y_train = Y_gen[0:num_examples, ...]
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)

# create placeholders
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_H, 100, 1))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 8))

# build graph
if (with_conv):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5],strides = 1, padding='valid',activation = tf.nn.relu)    
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, padding='valid')
else:
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(X, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, padding='valid')    
pool1_flat = tf.layers.flatten(pool1)
dense2 = tf.layers.dense(pool1_flat, units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu)
H = tf.layers.dense(dense2, units=8, activation=tf.nn.relu)

# compute cost
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y - H))

# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    a = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {X: X_train, Y:Y_train})
    print(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually, Segmentation fault means that your host doesn't have enough RAM to run the script. 
When you change the n_H value, even though you don't add any parameters to the convolutional layer, you add many parameters to the dense2 layer. Also, you add a lot of operations to the conv1 layer because the input is that much bigger.

It is perfectly possible that the ops and the 1600 parameters contained in the conv1 layer just finish to saturate you RAM and render your script unrunable. Try tracking your RAM usage using 'htop' or any other tracker.

Comment: I have 45 GB of RAM in my host. During the execution, my test script used up about 20 GB before segmentation fault, so there is plenty of memory left. I know there are a lot of parameters, but is a tensor input size of  (100, 4000, 100, 1) that large?

Comment: Just an update. When I was getting segmentation fault, I was running my script on a Centos 7.5 host. Then I ran my script on an OS X host, and it ran successfully! Why does it segmentation fault on my Centos 7 host?